# Neural network is not being trained, cross-entropy stays about the same

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have written the following multilayer perceptron model in TensorFlow, but it is not training. The accuracy stays around 9%, which is equivalent to random guessing, and cross-entropy stay around 2.56 and does not vary much.

The architecture is as follows:

```
def create_model(fingerprint_input, model_settings, is_training):
    if is_training:
        dropout_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='dropout_prob')
    fingerprint_size = model_settings['fingerprint_size']
    label_count = model_settings['label_count']
    weights_1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([fingerprint_size, 128], stddev=0.001))
    weights_2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([128, 128], stddev=0.001))
    weights_3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([128, 128], stddev=0.001))
    weights_out = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([128, label_count], stddev=0.001))
    bias_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([128]))
    bias_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([128]))
    bias_3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([128]))
    bias_out = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([label_count]))
    layer_1 = tf.matmul(fingerprint_input, weights_1) + bias_1
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    layer_2 = tf.matmul(layer_1, weights_2) + bias_2
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
    layer_3 = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights_3) + bias_3
    layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(layer_3)
    logits = tf.matmul(layer_3, weights_out) + bias_out
    if is_training:
        return logits, dropout_prob
    else:
        return logits
```

It takes the input size as `fingerprint_size` and the labels size as well as `label_count`. It has three hidden layers with 128 neurons each. I'm following the TensorFlow example on a speech data set, which provides a framework for everything else. In the documentation, all I needed to do is to include my own neural network architecture and my method should have those arguments defined and return the logits.

When I trained another predefined architecture, with the same inputs and output, the neural network trains. But this one is not training. Here is one predefined architecture:

```
def create_single_fc_model(fingerprint_input, model_settings, is_training):
  if is_training:
    dropout_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='dropout_prob')
  fingerprint_size = model_settings['fingerprint_size']
  label_count = model_settings['label_count']
  weights = tf.Variable(
      tf.truncated_normal([fingerprint_size, label_count], stddev=0.001))
  bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([label_count]))
  logits = tf.matmul(fingerprint_input, weights) + bias
  if is_training:
    return logits, dropout_prob
  else:
return logits
```

The learning rate are 0.001 for the first 15000 steps and 0.0001 for the last 3000 steps. These are the defaults. I also tried with 0.01 and 0.001, but the same result. I think the problem is somewhere in the above implementation.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try to increase standard deviation of randomly initialized weight variables, e.g. `stddev=0.1`, and initialize biases with non-zero values like: `tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[128])))`

Comment: @openmark Thank you! The problem was there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had potentially encountered a [vanishing gradient problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem), your variables were initialized with very small values (which is controlled by `stddev` parameter), it worked with one layer but in case of multiple layers it caused gradients to vanish during backpropagation.
Try to increase standard deviation of randomly initialized weight variables, e.g.

```
weights_n = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([a, b], stddev=0.1))
```

and initialize biases with non-zero values like

```
bias_n = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[b])))
```